# Why doesn't Team Arrow use codenames?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

There have been a number of times in *Arrow* that the team's communications have been compromised - both by foes and allies.

Given that nothing is entirely secure, and the fact that Oliver goes to <strike>great</strike> lengths to keep his identity secret, why is everyone addressed by their real name over the radio (this seems to be more frequent with Diggle and Felicity)?

Comment: Ollie's too cool to use code names.

Comment: By now, half the city knows who they are anyway. So why bother? Heck, I think Thea's the only one missing the joke at this point.

Comment: @Omegacron Nah, laughing too by now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common issue among modern superhero stories, both in movies/tv and in comics. Characters are too free with each others real names, and don't use code-names to hide their identities. In team-up stories, Batman and Superman routinely call each other "Clark" and "Bruce" in public, despite the fact that their lives would be ruined if their identities became public knowledge. I think it's a shift towards writers trying to show characters being friendly and intimate towards each other through the use of real names, with little thought to the logistics of keeping their identities secret, which is rarely used as an important story device these days

Comment: +1. Also worth noting: many Batman/Superman stories employ a dynamic of Batman referring to his teammates as "Superman" and "Wonder Woman", while Superman refers to his teammates as "Bruce" and "Diana".  It's a subtle way of showing the different ways they approach their identities: for Superman they're people performing jobs, while Batman considers them heroes first and foremost.

Answer (score 2):

They do, now. Team members have gradually started to use codenames. I believe the reasons they didn't was because of their uncertainty as to the "role" they were playing. Initially, they were all only temporarily working together. It's only recently that they've become a properly permanent team (except for Arsenal, who left). But they all now use codenames when dressed up. Even Speedy, as a codename, has been used by others even though it was originally just a nickname Oliver gave his sister.

At the moment the code names are as follows:

- Green Arrow (Oliver Queen)
- Arsenal (Roy Harper)
- Spartan (John Diggle)
- Speedy (Thea Queen)
- Black Canary (Laurel Lance)
- Overwatch (Felicity Smoak)